# How can I include Employer in display name?

Tags: tokens, settings, display

I have tried this but doesn't work. Can anyone suggest a correct token format please? Thanks

```
{contact.first_name}{ }{contact.last_name}{ }{contact.current_employer}
```

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? For GUI use, see [hook_civicrm_contact_get_displayname()](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_contact_get_displayname/)

Answer (score 1):

Tapash,

Unfortunately current_employer doesn't work for display even though the [code](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/CRM/Utils/Address.php#L141) is meant to handle.

Solution:

1. Submit a PR to handle for current employer.
2. Use pre hook to alter the display name just before it is written into the database.

HTH

Pradeep